# calculate the monthly average

Tags: c#, .net, date

I have the below list that has an object with two properties, Date and energy value, and I have to calculate the average energy per month.

The steps I need to follow are to find the start date and end date among all these and find the number of years, and then, each month need to calculate the average energy. If I see multiple months, I need to average the energy value.

```
public class DateEnergyValue 
{
   public DateOnly CollectedDate{ get; set; }
   public double Value { get; set; }
}

List<DateEnergyValue> DateEnergyValues = new List<DateEnergyValue>() { .....}
```

I can get the start date and end date like as below.

```
var startDate = DateEnergyValues.Min(a => a.CollectedDate);
var endDate = DateEnergyValues.Max(r=>r.CollectedDate);
```

I can get the number of years as well.

```
TimeSpan TS = startDate - endDate;
double Years = TS.TotalDays / 365.25;
```

But not sure how to go about the remaining calculation, and below the sample data image

| Collected Date(Month/Day/Year) | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 5/1/2009 | 2400 |
| 6/1/2009 | 2400 |
| 7/1/2009 | 2400 |
| 8/1/2009 | 7315.8 |
| 9/1/2009 | 5140.3 |
| 10/1/2009 | 1557.8 |
| 11/1/2009 | 1557.8 |
| 12/1/2009 | 369.7 |
| 1/1/2010 | 369.7 |
| 2/1/2010 | 144.8 |
| 3/1/2010 | 437.2 |
| 4/1/2010 | 804.1 |
| 5/1/2010 | 965.1 |
| 6/1/2010 | 1131 |
| 7/1/2010 | 1179.4 |
| 8/1/2010 | 1170.8 |
| 9/1/2010 | 993.6 |
| 10/1/2010 | 714.9 |
| 11/1/2010 | 244.3 |
| 12/1/2010 | 126.8 |
| 1/1/2011 | 122.1 |
| 2/1/2011 | 114.6 |
| 3/1/2011 | 185.2 |
| 4/1/2011 | 441.9 |
| 5/1/2011 | 1494.9 |
| 6/1/2011 | 1009.9 |
| 7/1/2011 | 3051.3 |
| 8/1/2011 | 3229.7 |
| 9/1/2011 | 996 |
| 10/1/2011 | 3328.7 |
| 11/1/2011 | 870.1 |
| 12/1/2011 | 1051.8 |
| 4/1/2011 | 481000 |
| 5/1/2011 | 446000 |
| 6/1/2011 | 608000 |
| 7/1/2011 | 323000 |
| 8/1/2011 | 478000 |
| 9/1/2011 | 452000 |
| 10/1/2011 | 505000 |
| 11/1/2011 | 438000 |
| 12/1/2011 | 456654 |

Could anyone please help with any ideas or suggestions with the same? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please do not put the sample data in an image. Include it as text, or best as a usable code fragment. Nobody is going to type all that data themselves. Help others in helping you.

Comment: What type is `Date`? Don't you mean DateTime or DateOnly?

Comment: @NineBerry, Sorry its DateOnly, I just updated the same

Comment: You need to specify the FORMAT of that date!  Is it `Day/Month/Year` or `Month/Day/Year`?

Comment: its not clear what 'average energy per month' even means. Is the answer 'you used 2500 per month in 09, 3500, in 11 etc' or is it average for each month, but whatr does that mean, you have the total for each month, what would the avg be?

Comment: @RufusL, if any month is missing from the list in a year, I need to count the value for the month as zero and I need to assume that each month in a year has the data with the above condition

Comment: @RufusL Don't write extensive answers in comments, please. Use the answer function instead.

Comment: So do you need the average value per month over all the time or per year? Please be more specific

Comment: @NineBerry, I would need both average value per month across the years and per year as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calculating the min and max date, you can iterate the months between those two dates and get an average for each one (leaving it zero if no matches were found for that month):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    // the supplied data as a pipe and comma delimited string
    String data = 
      "5/1/2009|2400,6/1/2009|2400,7/1/2009|2400,8/1/2009|7315.8,9/1/2009|5140.3," +
      "10/1/2009|1557.8,11/1/2009|1557.8,12/1/2009|369.7,1/1/2010|369.7," + 
      "2/1/2010|144.8,3/1/2010|437.2,4/1/2010|804.1,5/1/2010|965.1,6/1/2010|1131," + 
      "7/1/2010|1179.4,8/1/2010|1170.8,9/1/2010|993.6,10/1/2010|714.9,11/1/2010|244.3," +
      "12/1/2010|126.8,1/1/2011|122.1,2/1/2011|114.6,3/1/2011|185.2,4/1/2011|441.9," +
      "5/1/2011|1494.9,6/1/2011|1009.9,7/1/2011|3051.3,8/1/2011|3229.7,9/1/2011|996," +
      "10/1/2011|3328.7,11/1/2011|870.1,12/1/2011|1051.8,4/1/2011|481000,5/1/2011|446000," +
      "6/1/2011|608000,7/1/2011|323000,8/1/2011|478000,9/1/2011|452000,10/1/2011|505000," + 
      "11/1/2011|438000,12/1/2011|456654";

    List<DateEnergyValue> DateEnergyValues = new List<DateEnergyValue>();
    
    // this part just generates the list of instances:
    foreach(String pair in data.Split(",".ToCharArray())) {
      String[] values = pair.Split("|".ToCharArray());    
      DateEnergyValue dev = new DateEnergyValue();
      dev.CollectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0], "M/d/yyyy", null);
      dev.Value = double.Parse(values[1]);
      DateEnergyValues.Add(dev);      
    }

    // you provided this part:
    var minDate = DateEnergyValues.Min(a => a.CollectedDate);
    var maxDate = DateEnergyValues.Max(r => r.CollectedDate);

    List<DateEnergyValue> DateEnergyAverages = new List<DateEnergyValue>();
    
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(minDate.Year, minDate.Month, 1);
    DateTime stopDate = new DateTime(maxDate.Year, maxDate.Month, 1);
    while (startDate <= stopDate) {
      DateEnergyValue devAverage = new DateEnergyValue();
      devAverage.CollectedDate = startDate;
      var monthValues = DateEnergyValues.Where(x => x.CollectedDate.Year == startDate.Year && x.CollectedDate.Month == startDate.Month);
      if (monthValues.Count() > 0) {
        devAverage.Value = monthValues.Average(x => x.Value);
      }
      DateEnergyAverages.Add(devAverage);
      startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
    }

    foreach(DateEnergyValue dev in DateEnergyAverages) {
      Console.WriteLine(dev);
    }
  }
```

I added a `ToString()` to the class so it'll ouput:

```
using System;
public class DateEnergyValue 
{
  
  public DateTime CollectedDate{ get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }

  public override String ToString() {
    return $"Date: {CollectedDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")}, Value: {Value}";
  }
  
}
```

The generated output:

```
Date: 5/1/2009, Value: 2400
Date: 6/1/2009, Value: 2400
Date: 7/1/2009, Value: 2400
Date: 8/1/2009, Value: 7315.8
Date: 9/1/2009, Value: 5140.3
Date: 10/1/2009, Value: 1557.8
Date: 11/1/2009, Value: 1557.8
Date: 12/1/2009, Value: 369.7
Date: 1/1/2010, Value: 369.7
Date: 2/1/2010, Value: 144.8
Date: 3/1/2010, Value: 437.2
Date: 4/1/2010, Value: 804.1
Date: 5/1/2010, Value: 965.1
Date: 6/1/2010, Value: 1131
Date: 7/1/2010, Value: 1179.4
Date: 8/1/2010, Value: 1170.8
Date: 9/1/2010, Value: 993.6
Date: 10/1/2010, Value: 714.9
Date: 11/1/2010, Value: 244.3
Date: 12/1/2010, Value: 126.8
Date: 1/1/2011, Value: 122.1
Date: 2/1/2011, Value: 114.6
Date: 3/1/2011, Value: 185.2
Date: 4/1/2011, Value: 240720.95
Date: 5/1/2011, Value: 223747.45
Date: 6/1/2011, Value: 304504.95
Date: 7/1/2011, Value: 163025.65
Date: 8/1/2011, Value: 240614.85
Date: 9/1/2011, Value: 226498
Date: 10/1/2011, Value: 254164.35
Date: 11/1/2011, Value: 219435.05
Date: 12/1/2011, Value: 228852.9
```

Comment: I did not see any change in the generated output values compared to the original table; I believe the generated output you shared is not updated.

Comment: It definitely is. For example, for the month of December 2011, your had two entries:  `12/1/2011|1051.8` and  `12/1/2011|456654`. The average of `1051.8` and `456654` is `228852.9`, which is what shows up in my output as the last entry. If you're not getting the correct values then you haven't implemented the approach correctly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea of ​​how I could do it I'm not sure about the performance of it but I could do it

```
        List<DateEnergyValue> teste = new List<DateEnergyValue>();

        var primeiro = teste.GroupBy(x => new { mounth = x.CollectedDate.Month })
                            .Select(x => 
                                         new { 
                                             media = x.Average(p => p.Value), 
                                             mounth = x.Key.mounth 
                                         })
                            .ToList();
```

the list would be grouped by month and then create a new list from the grouping with an average of the groupings by month that would result in the value that needs the monthly average...

Hope this helps